# Two Text Links in the Same Row in Google Apps Add-On

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm working on an add-on based in the CardService functions in Google Apps Script. At one point in my UI, I want to have a pair of hyperlinks in the same "row" of the card (the first being left-aligned on the card, and the second being right-aligned).

Here's what I have so far:

```
    var urlText = CardService.newTextParagraph()
.setText("<a href ='" + shURL + "'>" + "File No. " + fileNo + "</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href ='" + folderURL + "'>" + "Drive Folder</a>")
```

Obviously the manual way is the wrong way to space the two out.

What do you think is the best way to do this? I see the Grid widget, but it doesn't seem to enable me to have separate hyperlinks. Same with the DecoratedText widget.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: According to documentation textParagraph supports basic HTML formatting.  It lists a few examples but none including alignment.

Comment: @Cooper Yes, that seems to be the case. I've tried a few different <p> tags, but without a defined CSS I think I'm dead in the water there. That's why I brought up Grid or DecoratedText.

Answer (score 1):

Summing up what's discussed in the comments, at the date of this answer [textParagraph()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-paragraph#setText(String)) provides [Text Formatting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/widgets#text_formatting) support but limited to:

```
Bold    = <b>test</b>
Italics = <i>test</i>
Underline   = <u>test</u>
Strikethrough = <s>test</s>
Font color =    <font color="#ea9999">test</font>
Hyperlink = <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
Time =  <time>2020-02-16 15:00</time>
Newline = test <br> test
```

Aside from the above, text alignment is not mentioned.

After testing *Grid* and *DecoratedText* options are also not suitable for this use case either. Also, be aware of the use of HTML/CSS for its format falls in one of the restrictions documented [here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/guides/workspace-restrictions#_use_htmlcss_or_client-side_scripting)

Since this is a missing feature, you may want to submit a [Feature Request](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features) so it may be considered in the future.

Comment: Thanks. This is already a feature request, or at least certain parts of it are captured in feature requests that I've seen. I'm frankly starting to wonder if there's still any development on add-ons/CardService; there sure hasn't been a significant advance in a while, and a lot of the functions lack access to new features in the rest of Workspace.